# Meaning (and History?) of "back of"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, history

I've come across the term "back of" (meaning "behind" in a physical or metaphorical sense) in a number of different works from around the turn of the 20th century*. Was this a linguistic fad of some sort that (thankfully) died out somewhere in the Twenties? When used, it seems to convey some kind of rhetorical emphasis which I notice but do not *feel*, if you know what I mean. It has a sort of *slangy* feel. Is there a story here?

<del>Also, it often consumes any article that might otherwise precede the next noun.</del> It suppresses a preceding preposition. *In back of* is written simply *back of*.

<sub>*. I'm an introverted intuitive and often I cannot access my full memories on a topic at first. So I don't presently remember which works they are, but if nobody freaks out about that and changes *the mood of the room* on me, I may very well remember shortly.</sub>

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the usage of the phrase?

Comment: Working on it...

Comment: Something like "Meet me at the _back of_ the pub".

Comment: Oh, rats. [Found it](http://books.google.com/books?id=OL60E3r2yiYC&lpg=PA83&dq=%22back%20of%22%20-the&pg=PA83#v=onepage&q=%22back%20of%22%20-the&f=false). I suppose it's general ref.

Comment: Yup! As in, _back of a coin_.

Comment: The usages where it just *sounds wrong* are more like: "Where's George?" "Over there, back of Frank." ... "The Infinite is the power *back of* the World."

Comment: It's been 10 hours, and still no meaningful context provided, so I'm closevoting as Not A Real Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OED has this:

> **15. back of:** back from, behind. (Esp. in U.S.). Cf. *in back of* at BACK *n.1* 23g.

Their first, last and a middling citation are:

> 1694   in *Cal. Virginia State Papers* (1875) I. 44   We Ranged on Ackoquane and so back of the Inhabitants and ye So[u]th.
>
> 1840   R. H. Dana *Two Years before Mast* ix,   The mission stands a little back of the town.
>
> 1953   M. Laski *Victorian Chaise Longue* 21   No one could live there, back of the railways, down by the canal.

There's also the remote *back of beyond*, first attested 1816.

Comment: Thanks for this. Oh, it's you! I've been arguing in favor of your answer on SO about [foo and bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868904/what-is-the-origin-of-foo-and-bar/6727104#6727104). Good work.

Comment: @luserdroog: Thanks :) The *foo/bar* question is quite long, but it has a summary at the top and it was really interesting to dig up its history. (And better than the others that are just links to reference sites.)

Answer (score 0):

We use the expression in the UK. It has the same meaning as "on the strength of", or "as a result of".

As an example:

Sam got the lead role in Macbeth on the **back of** his performance in Hamlet.

As to its origin, I couldn't say. However, it reminds me of the "standing on the shoulders of giants" phrase attributed to Newton. He could have said: "I got where I am today on the back of loads of people before me."